# Acoustic Steel: B String is E at 6th fret

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, fretboard

Picked up my acoustic steel string after a bit and noticed that whilst it was in tune the B string's E was up at the 6th fret.  It's annoying the heck out of me.  I've restrung it and same.

Open B is fine but it's flat up the fret board

Comment: Check the bridge/saddle hasn't moved. By checking the intonation at the 12th fret. The fretted note should be the same pitch as the harmonic there.

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid now.  I have to replace the nut. Slot cracked so obviously that's the reason that it's one fret up as the 1st fret is acting as the new nut

Comment: Don’t feel that way, you figured it out, didn’t you? You could try the crazy glue baking soda trick (just google it) to repair your old nut till you get a chance to change it. I’ve heard it works well enough that people have used it as a permanent repair.